# Is there a create-react-app alternative for Preact?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I'm thinking of switching from React to Preact.
I'm just wondering if there is a `create-react-app` alternative for Preact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation here](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started)

```
### Preact instalation
npm install -g preact-cli

### create react app equivalent
preact create default my-project

### Go into the generated project folder
cd my-project/

### Start the devserver
npm start
```